# How to cast nullable int to nullable short?

Tags: c#, int, type-conversion, nullable, short

The hits I get when I look for the answer refer to casting from *short* to *int* and from nullable to not-nullable. However, I get stuck on how to convert from a "larger" type *int?* to a "smaller" type *short?*.

The only way I can think of is writing a method like this:

```
private short? GetShortyOrNada(int? input)
{
  if(input == null)
    return (short?)null;
  return Convert.ToInt16(input.Value);
}
```

I wish to do that on a single line, though, because it's only done a single place in the entire code base for the project and won't ever be subject to change.

Comment: What's wrong with `short? s = (short?) i;` where `int? i = 5;`?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Please see [my comment to the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25525926/1525840). To answer your question - almost nothing is wrong with your suggestion. Accept of a certain assification on my side.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What's wrong with simple cast? I tested and that works fine.

```
private static short? GetShortyOrNada(int? input)
{
    checked//For overflow checking
    {
        return (short?) input;
    }
}
```

Comment: Gotta love "lifted" operators

Comment: This is embarrassing. I used *(short?)fromDb["field"]as int?* and it didn't compile. I forgot the parenthesis like so: *(short?)(fromDb["field"]as int?)*. I feel like a behind-part of the body a.k.a. the sitting device...

Answer (score 1):

You could replace a conditional statement with a conditional expression, like this:

```
short? res = input.HasValue ? (short?)Convert.ToInt16(input.Value) : null;
```

Comment: You don't need the ternary, casting a `null` value to a nullable will just give you `null` already.

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you're looking for?

```
private short? GetShortyOrNada(int? input)
{
  if(input == null)
    return (short?)null;
  if(input > Int16.MaxValue)
    return Int16.MaxValue;
  if(input < Int16.MinValue)
    return Int16.MinValue;
  return Convert.ToInt16(input.Value);
}
```

I just added IF clauses for the cases of too large values.

If you just want to return null if the value is not in the desired range:

```
private short? GetShortyOrNada(int? input)
{
  if(input == null || input < Int16.MinValue || input > Int16.MaxValue)
    return (short?)null;

  return Convert.ToInt16(input.Value);
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for. Indeed, you guard for values outside the limits of a *short* (+1 for that) but I'm looking for an in-line approach so I **won't have to** use a method. The limits in my particular case are always respected by the values already before I receive them.

Comment: My mistake, i missed this detail and learned from the answer you accepted ;-)